# Running an iPhone app on the device only shows a white screen

Tags: iphone

I have a strange problem when I try to deploy my current app to the device.

Once it is successfully pushed down I see the Default.png as it loads, then the first view appears for about 1/10 second and the whole screen goes white. It feels like the it is a resolution issue or similar as I can still interact with the text fields. When I touch the text field the keyboard appears as normal and I can type in. I can also click-hold in the text field and the magnifying glass appears and shows everything underneath.

I have tried displaying a different view at launch to see if it was specific to the first view but to no avail.

I also tried a different device and it also happens there.

I am using iOS SDK 4.0.2 and the devices are 3.1.3 & 3.1.2

P.S. This all worked fine up to a few weeks ago, but I'm not sure what has changed to make this happen.

Thanks in advance
Liam

Edit:

The app works perfectly in the simulator.

---

[image]

---

Snippet of the code to display the view. It's a very simple page that is displayed if the person is not logged in. In the image the magnifying glass is in the 'username' field. This works fine in the simulator.

```
LoginPageViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginPage" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Can you post some code?  Showing what's going on in your App Delegate and Root View Controller will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the 'Main nib file base name' in the project's plist was loading a blank view on top of the view I was creating.

I still do not know why this only happened on the device and not on the simulator? perhaps a speed issue when loading?